# How can I define different JSON mappings to the same model object in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, mapping

I'm writing a Swift app that has search functionality that will look for similar data from different databases/sources. In other words, the results from these different sources should be backed by the same model object.

Given that each online JSON source will return JSON data representing the same model, but the JSON being slightly different between each online source. What is the best way to encode/decode to and from the different sources but into the same model?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your common model object requires the following values: (fullName, age)

And you have 02 sources of data which returns slightly different types of the same information:

**Source 01**

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": "25"
}
```

**Source 02**

```
{
    "fullName": "Jane Doe"
    "dob": "10-02-1990"
}
```

As long as you know that a given source produces a fixed response, I would suggest a model class per response as follows:

**Response01**

```
struct Reponse01: Decodable {
    let _firstName: String
    let _lastName: String
    let _age: Int
}
```

**Response02**

```
struct Reponse02: Decodable {
    let _fullName: String
    let _dob: Date
}
```

Then define a common protocol that can be used to extract the necessary information from your individual model structs:

```
protocol BaseModelDerivable {
    var fullName: String { get }
    var age: Int { get }
}
```

And then make your individual response classes implement this interface while defining the method of how the computed properties are returned. Ex:

```
struct Reponse01: Decodable {
    let _firstName: String
    let _lastName: String
    let _age: Int
}

extension Reponse01: BaseModelDerivable {
    var fullName: String { 
        get { return "\(_firstName) \(_lastName)" }
    }
    var age: Int {
        get { return _age }  
    }
}
```

This way you can have a heterogeneous collection of varying models using the `BaseModelDerivable` protocol (inside an array of `[BaseModelDerivable]`).
When retrieving from some storage, you can repopulate this array by querying for each individual item and storing in a `[BaseModelDerivable]` collection.

**Note:** While there may be other methods to do this like making a struct called `BaseModel` and writing multiple initializers that will create this object from either of these responses, your model object will start to get littered with initializers when the sources are numerous.

```
struct BaseModel {
    let fullName: String
    let age: Int

    convenience init(aResponse: Response01) {
        let fullName = "\(aResponse.firstName) \(aResponse.lastName)"
        let age = aResponse.age
        init(fullName: fullName, age: age)
    }

    // another init for Response02

    // how many more??
}
```

**Note:** You may also consider writing a `Converter<T>` class that takes in any of the varying responses and spit out a `BaseModel` value.

Many ways to do this. Hope this helps.